# javascript error in ie7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I am getting a javascript error on a page with this code.The error is *"parentNode is null or not and object"*

The error is in this line: `theParent.parentNode.removeChild(theParent);`

Is there some other code I can use to replace this or jquery that
 will work instead?

```
var path = location.pathname;

if( path == "/SearchResults.asp" 
 || path == "/ProductDetails.asp" 
 || path.indexOf("-s/") != -1 
 || path.indexOf("_s/") != -1 
 || path.indexOf("_p/") != -1 
 || path.indexOf("-p/") != -1 ) {
    var links = document.getElementById("content_area")
                        .getElementsByTagName("a");
    var homeLink;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].innerHTML.match("Home")) {
                homeLink = links[i];
                break;
        }
    }
    var theParent = homeLink.parentNode;
    theParent.parentNode.removeChild(theParent);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a complete page, so we can test this ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (theParent) { theParent.parentNode.removeChild(theParent); }
```

Since, it looks like you may not be finding the innerHTML, "Home" or not creating theParent for some other reason.

The HTML would help, just to make sure Home exists and that it has a grand parent.

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange that you'd get "*parentNode is null or not and object*" with:

```
var theParent = homeLink.parentNode;
```

If anything, it would simply set `theParent` to `null` and continue on.  Or, `homeLink` would need to be the cause of the error, which is not what IE is complaining about.

However, the next line...

```
theParent.parentNode.removeChild(theParent);
```

...I could see throwing the error mentioned if `parentNode` was `null`, since `null` cannot have methods, such as `removeChild`.

You can try revising the line to something like the following to get an idea of success rate:

```
if (theParent.parentNode == null) // == for null or undefined by coercion
    theParent.parentNode.removeChild(theParent);
else
    throw new Error('Node could not be removed as parentNode is unknown.');
```

Or, leave out the `else` and `throw` to let it fail silently.

Comment: my appologies, the error is in  theParent.parentNode.removeChild(theParent);

Answer (score 0):

It seems your loop may not be finding a link with the text `Home`. Have you tried checking if homeLink is null?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either homeLink is null or the parentNode is null. Can you run it in firefox + firebug and set breakpoints?